# Micro SD Card automatically getting write protected

Tags: sd-card

I'm using Transcend Micro SD Card. When I try to copy some files from my system(12.04), it's getting write protected and also unmounting the device. I'm unable to copy files to it.

Answer (score 4):

In case, if you are using Sandisk, please do the following (If the lock switch is not on lock):

1. Slide the switch up and down. Repeat this 3 times.
2. Let it stay on the Lock position for 30 seconds.
3. Slide the switch up to unlock the card.
4. Try to transfer files into the device.

Yes it is strange and yes it works, as per this [source](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Desktop-PC-Questions/Problem-writing-to-SD-cards/td-p/200852).

Comment: Doesn't work for me - maybe, because it is a Transcend card.

Comment: I try few times did not work, but more time eject it and try to past normal file in card storage, once file copied, than I able to write all and wirte image too

Answer (score 2):

Rahul, First Check that whether You have locked MicroSD card using white lock which is located on side of Adapter.

Comment: There's no lock for the SDCard holder. Are you saying that the problem may be with SDCard USB holder ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate.
Please refer to my answer on /questions/213889/

basically, just run in terminal `sudo mount --options remount,rw <the SDHC drive, /dev/sdb for example, find it using fdisk -l>`

Comment: Doesn't work for me either.